# so built that vs built so that

Tags: grammar

> 1. This bridge is so built that it can be open in the middle.
> 2. This bridge is built so that it can be open in the middle.

I wonder which one is correct English and what is the difference in meaning.
I think they're all correct English and the meaning of each sentence is below.

> 3. This bridge is built in the manner that it can be open in the middle.
> 4. This bridge is built for the purpose that it can be open in the middle.

I want to know whether my thinking is right.

Comment: In #1 "so built" would refer to what was previously stated, for example "The bridge has a tower at each end."

Comment: @WeatherVane But, there's some native speakers who insist that sentence 1 is wrong. You agree with them?

Comment: It's not wrong, but is unusual without a preceding clause as suggested. What is wrong, is that each sentence should *probably* say "...be open***ed***..." Sentence #2 is the best.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for pointing out the error. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I would interpret #1 as "This bridge is built to such a high degree that it can be open in the middle" - as in, if it were any less built, it could not be open.

Comment: Please don't edit the post. You asked what you asked, and SE is not a "free-flow" dynamic exchange, otherwise the original question will be lost and it won't make any sense why it was asked.

Comment: @WeatherVane I got it.

Comment: @Juhasz Do you think "so" is used as an intensifier?

Comment: Sort of.  It looks like this meaning from *Merriam-Webster* "2a(1) : to an indicated or suggested extent or degree."  The same as, "The bridge was so long that I couldn't see the end of it."

Comment: I disagree, sorry. Here the "so built" means "built like this", or "thus built".

Comment: A round thing is so made that it rolls on a slope (it happens to roll); it is made so that it rolls on a slope (it is intended to roll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** I think they're all correct English, I want to know whether my thinking is right?**

**Well I know you will all mark me down for this answer but!!!** First tidy up the English!

How can we be debating this question. How can we have a **bridge** is so **built that** it can **be open in the middle**. The word has to be **Opened** or in the middle has to be deleted. Which leaves us with

> This bridge is `so`(in this way) built that it can be opened in the middle.
>
> This bridge is built `so`(in this way) that it can be opened in the middle.

or

> This bridge is (in this way) `so` built that it can open
>
> This bridge is built `so`(in this way) that it can open
>
> **so** adverb [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so)(IN THIS WAY) in this way, or like this:
>
> **Example** The pillars, which are outside the building, are so placed in order to provide the maximum space inside
>
> **adverb**; noun; [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adverb) a word that describes or gives more information about a verb, adjective, adverb, or phrase:
>
> **Adverbs: position**; We can put adverbs and adverb phrases at the front, in the middle or at the end of a clause [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)

Now we can see that **the debate is not necessary** as the adverb can be placed anywhere as long as we tidy up (Tense, word order etc.) the phrase that surrounds it.